# Regex to get everything in between

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I need to get content from below query which is ending with [PT] and also inside that which text which has $ at the end.

```
17 and  ( am restaur$ or food$[]produc$ )[PT]
*neo$ &  ( bruch$ | curl$ | hair$ )[PT]
( computer$ or software$ or hardware$ or peripheral$ or conductor$ )[PT]
```

Expected outcome :
am restaur,food,produc ...

I tried with below REGEX

```
(?<=[(])(.*)(?=([)][[]PT))
```

it gives only text in between [PT]

Comment: Well, you could explain what you tried - that would clarify what you are trying to achieve. Also, what tag is relevant: JS or C#?

Comment: Ok, so you are using C#. Try `Regex.Matches(str, @"\w+(?=\$)")`

Comment: Note that `*neo$` is not inside `(....)` and you tried to get the substring between parentheses. Something here  just does not click. Sorry, your question is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regular expression (Javascript),

```
k.match(/(\w*)\$/g).join("").split("$");
```

where `k` contains your string eg: k = `"17 and  ( restaur$ or food$[]produc$ )[PT]"`; here `\w` will match all word characters and match function returns all matches from the string.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below uses 2 regex patterns.
The first one to get the PT content.
And the second to get the values from those matches.

```js
var str = "17 and  ( restaur$ or food$[]produc$ )[PT]\
*neo$ &  ( bruch$ | curl$ | hair$ )[PT]\
( computer$ or software$ or hardware$ or peripheral$ or conductor$ )[PT]\
16 and ( illumination$ [TS] ) and ( racing | ( auto$ adj rac$ ) | auto$ | car )[PT]";

//var re1 = /\([^()]*?\)\[PT\]/g;
var re1 = /\((?:[^()]*?(?:\(.*\)(?!\[)))*[^()]*?\)\[PT\]/g;
var re2 = /\w+(?=\$)/g;

var matchArray = [];
var m1, m2;

while (m1 = re1.exec(str)) {
    console.log(m1[0]);
    while (m2 = re2.exec(m1[0])) {
       matchArray.push(m2[0]);
    }
}

console.log(matchArray);
```

Comment: this seems to for for some but for below 
"34 and  '41'[TS] and  ( racing | ( auto$ adj rac$ ) | auto$ | car )[PT]";
getting null in this case

Comment: @Prithvi  That's because the pattern for re1 assumes there are no nested parentheses. Changed the first regex so it'll catch a bit more of the PT's.  Although without recursion in standard javascript regex I don't see now how you would catch every possible case for nested stuff.